# Count in how many categories an item appears - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible to achieve the result from Column C using Google Sheets formula?

[image]

I was able to count using Query and Unique, but the result is grouped by item. I need the result in a separate column for every item in the list.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example, use the following in C2:

```
=map(B2:B9,lambda(each,countuniqueifs(A2:A9,B2:B9,each)))
```

Comment: That's great! I had not included in my example the case where there may be duplicates in the Item column. Your solution covers this aspect too!